# ANTLR: call a rule from a different grammar

Tags: antlr, grammar, modularity, rule

is it possible to invoke a rule from a different grammar? 
the purpose is to have two languages in the same file, the second language starting by an (begin ...) where ... is in the second language. the grammar should invoke another grammar to parse that second language.

for example:

```
grammar A;

start_rule
    :    '(' 'begin' B.program ')' //or something like that
    ;
```

```
grammar B;

program
    :   something* EOF
    ;

something
    : ...
    ;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question could be interpreted in (at least) two ways:

1. separate rules from a large grammar into separate grammars;
2. parse a separate language inside your "main" language (island grammar).

I assume it's the first, in which case you can import grammars.

### A demo for option 1:

### file: L.g

```java
lexer grammar L;

Digit
  :  '0'..'9'
  ;
```

### file: Sub.g

```java
parser grammar Sub;

number
  :  Digit+
  ;
```

### file: Root.g

```java
grammar Root;

import Sub;

parse
  :  number EOF {System.out.println("Parsed: " + $number.text);}
  ;
```

### file: Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    L lexer = new L(new ANTLRStringStream("42"));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    RootParser parser = new RootParser(tokens);
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

### Run the demo:

```
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/Composite$ java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool L.g
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/Composite$ java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool Root.g 
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/Composite$ javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/Composite$ java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
```

which will print:

```
Parsed: 42
```

to the console.

More info, see: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Composite+Grammars

### A demo for option 2:

A nice example of a language inside a language is regex. You have the "normal" regex language with its meta characters, but there's another one in it: the language that describes a character set (or character class).

Instead of accounting for the meta characters of a character set (range `-`, negation `^`, etc.) inside your regex-grammar, you could simply consider a character set as a single token consisting of a `[` and then everything up to and including `]` (with possibly `\]` in it!) inside your regex-grammar. When you then stumble upon a `CharSet` token in one of your parser rules, you invoke the CharSet-parser.

### file: Regex.g

```java
grammar Regex;

options { 
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  REGEX;
  ATOM;
  CHARSET;
  INT;
  GROUP;
  CONTENTS;
}

@members {
  public static CommonTree ast(String source) throws RecognitionException {
    RegexLexer lexer = new RegexLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    RegexParser parser = new RegexParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    return (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();
  }
}

parse
  :  atom+ EOF -> ^(REGEX atom+)
  ;

atom
  :  group quantifier?     -> ^(ATOM group quantifier?)
  |  EscapeSeq quantifier? -> ^(ATOM EscapeSeq quantifier?)
  |  Other quantifier?     -> ^(ATOM Other quantifier?)
  |  CharSet quantifier?   -> ^(CHARSET {CharSetParser.ast($CharSet.text)} quantifier?)
  ;

group
  :  '(' atom+ ')' -> ^(GROUP atom+)
  ;

quantifier
  :  '+'
  |  '*'
  ;

CharSet
  :  '[' (('\\' .) | ~('\\' | ']'))+ ']'
  ;

EscapeSeq
  :  '\\' .
  ;

Other
  :  ~('\\' | '(' | ')' | '[' | ']' | '+' | '*')
  ;
```

### file: CharSet.g

```java
grammar CharSet;

options { 
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  NORMAL_CHAR_SET;
  NEGATED_CHAR_SET;
  RANGE;
}

@members {
  public static CommonTree ast(String source) throws RecognitionException {
    CharSetLexer lexer = new CharSetLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    CharSetParser parser = new CharSetParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    return (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();
  }
}

parse
  :  OSqBr ( normal  -> ^(NORMAL_CHAR_SET normal)
           | negated -> ^(NEGATED_CHAR_SET negated)
           ) 
     CSqBr
  ;

normal
  :  (EscapeSeq | Hyphen | Other) atom* Hyphen?
  ;

negated
  :  Caret normal -> normal
  ;

atom
  :  EscapeSeq
  |  Caret
  |  Other
  |  range
  ;

range
  :  from=Other Hyphen to=Other -> ^(RANGE $from $to)
  ;

OSqBr
      :  '['
  ;

CSqBr
  :  ']'
  ;

EscapeSeq
  :  '\\' .
  ;

Caret
  :  '^'
  ;

Hyphen
  :  '-'
  ;

Other
  :  ~('-' | '\\' | '[' | ']')
  ;
```

### file: Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CommonTree tree = RegexParser.ast("((xyz)*[^\\da-f])foo");
    DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
    StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
    System.out.println(st);
  }
}
```

And if you run the main class, you will see the [DOT output](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php) for the regex `((xyz)*[^\\da-f])foo` which is the following tree:

[image]

The magic is inside the `Regex.g` grammar in the `atom` rule where I inserted a tree node in a rewrite rule by invoking the static `ast` method from the `CharSetParser` class:

```
CharSet ... -> ^(... {CharSetParser.ast($CharSet.text)} ...)
```

Note that inside such rewrite rules, there must *not* be a semi colon! So, this would be wrong: `{CharSetParser.ast($CharSet.text);}`.

### EDIT

And here's how to create tree walkers for both grammars:

### file: RegexWalker.g

```java
tree grammar RegexWalker;

options {
  tokenVocab=Regex;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

walk
  :  ^(REGEX atom+) {System.out.println("REGEX: " + $start.toStringTree());}
  ;

atom
  :  ^(ATOM group quantifier?)
  |  ^(ATOM EscapeSeq quantifier?)
  |  ^(ATOM Other quantifier?)
  |  ^(CHARSET t=. quantifier?) {CharSetWalker.walk($t);}
  ;

group
  :  ^(GROUP atom+)
  ;

quantifier
  :  '+'
  |  '*'
  ;
```

### file: CharSetWalker.g

```java
tree grammar CharSetWalker;

options {
  tokenVocab=CharSet;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

@members {
  public static void walk(CommonTree tree) {
    try {
      CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(tree);
      CharSetWalker walker = new CharSetWalker(nodes);
      walker.walk();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

walk
  :  ^(NORMAL_CHAR_SET normal)  {System.out.println("NORMAL_CHAR_SET: " + $start.toStringTree());}
  |  ^(NEGATED_CHAR_SET normal) {System.out.println("NEGATED_CHAR_SET: " + $start.toStringTree());}
  ;

normal
  :  (EscapeSeq | Hyphen | Other) atom* Hyphen?
  ;

atom
  :  EscapeSeq
  |  Caret
  |  Other
  |  range
  ;

range
  :  ^(RANGE Other Other)
  ;
```

### Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CommonTree tree = RegexParser.ast("((xyz)*[^\\da-f])foo");
    CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(tree);
    RegexWalker walker = new RegexWalker(nodes);
    walker.walk();
  }
}
```

To run the demo, do:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool CharSet.g 
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool Regex.g
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool CharSetWalker.g
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool RegexWalker.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
```

which will print:

```
NEGATED_CHAR_SET: (NEGATED_CHAR_SET \d (RANGE a f))
REGEX: (REGEX (ATOM (GROUP (ATOM (GROUP (ATOM x) (ATOM y) (ATOM z)) *) (CHARSET (NEGATED_CHAR_SET \d (RANGE a f))))) (ATOM f) (ATOM o) (ATOM o))
```

Comment: actually it was the second question, i will edit it in the post to clarify that. but can't the second question be answered in the same way? it looks exactly like a solution for that.

Comment: @Sebastian, you might get away with a composite grammar: it all depends on what languages you're trying to parse (how their lexer differ). You could try of course. If it fails, please edit your question with a real example of something you're trying to parse.

Comment: @Sebastian, I added an example of how I should handle such island grammars.

Comment: one additional question: how can the (sub-)tree from the other grammer which is mounted  in ^(ATOM {CharSetParser.ast($CharSet.text)} quantifier?) be referenced in a tree grammar?

Comment: i'm afraid it's not possible to have two seperate tree walkers? thanks anyway

Comment: @Sebastian, not sure, but I think it is possible.

Comment: my idea would be to pass not a direct subtree to the rewrite rule but instead only the Charset token and to call the Parser function with the token in the treewalker, were i could invoke the other treewalker as well. i well try that tomorrow, today is my day off :) what do you think?

Comment: @Sebastian, not entirely sure what you mean, sorry. However, I edited my answer so that it uses 2 tree walkers (1 for each combined grammar). The key is that you simply use the `.` (dot) meta-char inside the Regex tree walker that denoted your CharSet-tree. Note that I edited the combined grammars above the **EDIT** slightly!